# Prolog invert elements into a list

Tags: prolog

I need some words about my assignment and my solution:

Define a statement to invert two parameters, one list and other second list which has its elements in reverse order. We CANT use reverse built-in.

```
Example:

> invierte( [a, [b, c], d, [e, f]], L)

L = [[e, f], d, [b, c], a]
```

My propose:

```
invierte([],[]).
invierte([X],[X]).
invierte([H|T], Result) :-
invierte([T|H]), Result).
```

My doubt is would I need to divide the input first list in the general case as:

```
invierte([H|T], Result) :-
invierte([T|H]), Result).
```

or

```
invierte([H,Y|T], Result) :-
invierte([Y,H|T]), Result).
```

Thank you for your tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take from the top of one stack and put to the top of a new stack -- it is reversed:

```
list_rev(L, R) :-
    list_rev(L, [], R). % "[]" is the new stack

list_rev([], R, R). % When original stack is empty the new stack is done
list_rev([X|Xs], Ys, R) :- % "[X|Xs]" takes X from the top of Xs
    list_rev(Xs, [X|Ys], R). % ... and puts it on the top of Ys
```

there

```
?- list_rev([a, [b, c], d, [e, f]], R).
R = [[e, f], d, [b, c], a].
```

Comment: Thank you User9213 for your help. I understood it clearly and straightforward because of your comments. Also I learnt that I can be constrained by number of input arguments but I can use recursive calls to add more inputs to that definition. Also I have one doubt, at LINE 4:  list_rev([], R, R). Why do we put "R" as the second parameter which is supposed to be the reversed stack; obviously I do accept to put it on the third one which is the returned result, but I wouldn't have put the second one as you did by myself, maybe you could explain further!

Comment: @enoy maybe explaining helps you or maybe it only makes you think that you understand but in fact you just think you understand better but still cannot write your own predicates on your own. The difference is that when there is detailed explanation you can nod your head and **agree** with explanation but still not grasp the idea. It is easy to agree but difficult to make your own propositions and then decide how to turn your propositions into solutions then ensure that your solution correctly implements your proposition. Think about it or maybe not?

Answer (score 3):

You can use foldl and difference lists :

```
:-use_module(library(lambda)).

inverse(In, Out) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^append_dl([X|U]-U, Y, Z), In, V-V, Out-[]).

append_dl(A-B, B-C, A-C).
```

For example

```
 ?- inverse([1,2,3], X).
X = [3,2,1].
```

**EDIT**
After second version of User9213 we can write

```
:-use_module(library(lambda)).

inverse(In, Out) :-
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^Z=[X|Y], In, [], Out).
```

Comment: Wait does your solution somehow guard agains circular lists? I wrote another easier answer but your is probably cleverer, where is this library(lambda)?

Comment: lambda.pl is a library from SWI-Prolog. My solution doesn't work with circular lists, but are circular lists regular lists ? reverse doesn't work too with circular lists. append_dl concats lists in O(1) when append concats lists in O(len of the first arg of append).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it more fancy but not too fancy you can use foldl like this:

```
list_rev_foldl([], []).
list_rev_foldl([X|Xs], R) :-
    foldl(rev, Xs, [X], R).

rev(X, Ys, [X|Ys]).
```

Answer (score 3):

When describing lists, DCGs usually yield easily readable code. Also let's pick a more declarative name, that reflects the relational nature of predicates, say list_invlist/2. Then you describe what an inverted list looks like:

```
list_invlist(L,I) :-      % the inverse of the list L
   phrase(invseq(L),I).   % is described by invseq//1

invseq([]) -->            % the inverse of the empty list
   [].                    % is the empty list
invseq([X|Xs]) -->        % the inverse of the list [X|Xs] is
   invseq(Xs),            % the inverse of the list Xs
   [X].                   % followed by X
```

The example query from your post:

```
   ?- list_invlist([a,[b,c],d,[e,f]],I).
I = [[e,f],d,[b,c],a]
```

Note that the predicate can also be used in the other direction, just like its relational name suggests. However, after yielding the first solution list_invlist/2 loops.

```
   ?- list_invlist(L,[[e,f],d,[b,c],a]).
L = [a,[b,c],d,[e,f]] ? ;
...                                        % <- loop
```

That is due to the left-recursion in the recursive rule of invseq//2. You can remedy that by adding a constraint in list_invlist/2 that restricts both lists to the same length (the DCG-rules remain unchanged):

```
list_invlist(L,I) :-
   samelength(L,I),
   phrase(invseq(L),I).

samelength([],[]).
samelength([X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :-
   samelength(Xs,Ys).
```

Now the predicate terminates for the second query as well:

```
   ?- list_invlist(L,[[e,f],d,[b,c],a]).
L = [a,[b,c],d,[e,f]]
```

And you have not used built-ins or libraries for the solution so far.